# PHP str_replace into microsoft word template

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word

Right now I'm get task to make generate contract letter function in HRMS.
I'm already using CKEditor but the result is very different since  the purpose made CKEditor is not like Microsoft Word or Google Docs purpose.

So I'm having idea that I'm making the template first in Microsoft Word and use PHP function str_replace to passing the data into Microsoft Word template.

The question is :
1. With that flow, is it possible to do that?
2. If Question 1 is possible can you hit me with the sample?

Many Thanks,
Hendra

Comment: why not simply try it yourself if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several Classes that can do at least part of what you are trying to do:

- [wrklst/docxmustache](https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache)
- [openTBS – Tiny But Strong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php)
- [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)
- [docxtemplater pro](https://modules.docxtemplater.com) (basic opensource / free version / MIT license available as of writing; image replacing is a commercial plugin)
- [docxpresso](http://www.docxpresso.com) (commercial)
- [phpdocx](https://www.phpdocx.com) (commercial)

The first 4 of these are at least partially open source and investigating the code will help you understand the process, which is not trivial with word. In addition you can check out http://officeopenxml.com for the format details.

The main problem I see is with proper HTML to openXML conversion. Meaning to convert the styling from CKEditor (which might be HTML) into the proper XML Styling, which functions quite differently and a direct translation is not trivial. Check out https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache/blob/master/src/WrkLst/DocxMustache/HtmlConversion.php so see some basic HTML conversion on singular runs of bold, italic and underlined text.

To my knowledge there is no maintained open source package that delivers proper html to openxml conversion. If you need this and cannot write it yourself, you will probably go for one of the paid solutions.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Docx is a zipped format that contains some xml. If you want to build a simple replace {tag} by value system, it can already become complicated, because the {tag} is internally separated into `<w:t>{</w:t><w:t>tag</w:t><w:t>}</w:t>`. If you want to embed loops to iterate over an array, it becomes a real hassle.

source : https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/goals.html

You could use the library I created in answer for this problem : https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater , it works with JS in the browser or with node.js.